# Ping seems to send packets but not receiving them (please can somebody help)

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns, ping, tethering

I'm tethering Internet from my phone to Ubuntu (18.04.3 LTS bionic) it was working fine until suddenly stopped working, I can't access Internet
When I try google.com in Firefox it says:

> **The connection has timed out**

Here's results from ping:

```
> ping -c 1 google.com -v
ping: socket: Permission denied, attempting raw socket...
ping: socket: Permission denied, attempting raw socket...
PING google.com (172.217.17.14) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

And nslookup:

```
> nslookup google.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.17.14
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4003:802::200e
```

I didn't set any proxy I tried restarting the computer and tried this

```
sudo iptables -F && sudo ufw disable
```

But still no results

I tried to live boot to Kali I face the same problem

Comment: No internet is working fine on my phone I think the problem is the first two lines that comes from ping